# Combine document ready and self-invoking function

Tags: jquery

I am doing this, often. The reason for the self-invoking function is that I am often in WordPress, where it's in noconflict mode .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
(function ($) {         
        //do things     
})(jQuery);
});
```

Am I doing it right? Is there a shortcut, to do both things at once?

I just found

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
  // Your code using failsafe $ alias here...
});
```

Does this do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options for operating in no-conflict mode are as follows (as per the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/))

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

OR

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```